# TYPO3 pw_comments change/translate labels

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I like to change the labels of `pw_comments` to german.
Until now I've tried to work with TypoScript, but this does not work:

```
plugin.tx_pwcomments._LOCAL_LANG.default.tx_pwcomments.comment = Kommentar
```

The page is in german language only, for that reason it is fine to change the defaults.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible resolution is to copy

```
typo3conf/ext/pw_comments/Resources/Private/Language/de.locallang.xlf
```

to

```
typo3conf/l10n/de/pw_comments/Resources/Private/Language/de.locallang.xlf
```

what do you think about this?

Answer (score 1):

regarding language indexes `default` means english in TYPO3.
you need to differentiate between your current language and the language index for translations.

in this way you need to use
`plugin.tx_pwcomments._LOCAL_LANG.de.tx_pwcomments.comment = Kommentar`
to set a german label if you have configured your site to use german language (which you should do to have a clean language handling).

[image: Language Configuration in TYPO3 for German as only language]

and don't forget to load all german translations:

`ADMIN TOOLS` -> `Maintenance` -> `Manage Language Packs` ->
`ADMINWERKZEUGE` -> `Wartung` -> `Manage Language Packs` ->  (German BackEnd Labels)
[image: Manage Language Packs]

Comment: I have now changed it as you suggested. Unfortunately it still does not work. How can I query the current language setting? My language setting in page configuration is set to "German"

Comment: another way to change translations is to change the localized strings in the language files stored beyond `/typo3conf/l10n/`. of course after you get the translations from central server and with the knowing that after an update your changes need to be reapplied.

Comment: when I look into the sources of ext:pw_comments I see german language files with exact your translation. that gives a hint, that you have not loaded all translations or that your language configuration is not working well.

Comment: I have exactly the same configuration as shown in your screenshots for this url - but it is still not working. how can I check my language configuration?

Comment: I think "German" should be available in the list of active languages (second screenshot). Then the download should run without errors.

Comment: I checked /typo3conf/l10n/de/pw_comments/Resources/Private/Language/de.locallang.xlf and found english version only .

      <trans-unit id="tx_pwcomments.newComment.name" xml:space="preserve">
        <source>Your name:</source>

Comment: clean translations in: https://bitbucket.org/ArminVieweg/pw_comments/src/master/Resources/Private/Language/de.locallang.xlf (last commit from 2018-06). either your version is too old or broken?